# Is it good to rewrite properties like parent.document

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am currently Working on IE,And make a Live editor Application that shows output on a `iframe`,
And i don't want to use `Sandbox` options to protect my parent and it is necessary to me to keep `iframe` on `same domain` ,

So if i use :

```
var obj = parent.document.getElementById('some_parent_id');
obj.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Then ,my `parent` html got changes ,

So , I find the solution for that to rewrite the `parent.document`

Such as :

```
var parent = {
  document: false,
}
```

Now when i apply the above code on `iframe` to change in my `parent` then it just show me error that unable to get property `getElementById` of undefined !

Now for `IE` it is working fine ..So it is good to do so ? or there is another way to access `parent` from `iframe` ?

Comment: It works in chrome. On which browser it doesn't work?

Comment: You want to avoid letting the user change the iframe? He can do so anyway by using chrome's inspect element, or just running a script from the parent page's console...

Comment: it works but ,i want to know that is it good or thier is another option to change `parent` ? @sabof

Comment: You,right ,It doesn't affect anything but ,user only change the design(UI) for a session... So is it good ? @TastySpaceApple

Comment: Well, design-wise, I wouldn't even try to control what the user does at his end - I can't control it. If the user wants the whole page to be red, just let him. (Even if it were programitically possible to stop him in javascript, he can always put Cellophane his screen. :)) He gets a finished product, if he wants to ruin it - that's his business.

Comment: @AshishMishra Oh, I see. The code in the iframe will still have access to parent's cookies. Personally I'd either go for another domain, or not bother with such issues at all.

Comment: @sabof If he wrote the code, he has access to his cookies anyway. But I see what you mean. If you're writing a platform like jsfiddle, where people can *share code*, then access to cookies etc would be a serious security vulnerability.

Comment: Actually its a Desktop application only.. and not used any Internet connectivity ! but works on IE platform !@TastySpaceApple

Comment: @TastySpaceApple,You right,let user change ,what ever he want ! but it only for a session ... :))

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you're trying to do. I mean, you control the iframe's code, don't you, so how could it be used to change the parent's document?

Anyway, with your solution you aren't changing `parent.document`, you are redefining the `parent` property of the iframe. However, it is still possible to get acces to the parent document, via `window.top.document`.

Comment: Thanks,You right! actually i attached a `JS` file with the `iframe`,that have my code that unable the user to,change in `parent`, your snippet is works and it also able to access the `parent`,so is there a way to stop accessing ? @Oscar Paz

Comment: Well, you could redefine the `parent` and `top` properties of the window object of the document in the iframe. I think those are the only properties with a reference to the parent window, though I'm not completely sure. The best way to know would be to open the developers tools, and examine all the properties of the window object.

Comment: How to redefine them ,as i do is it the same ? or the another way to redefine them ? It is very imp. to me,to protect my App form this bug!! @Oscar Paz

Comment: the same way you did: `window.parent = window.top = undefined`.

Comment: ,is there any other way to select parent document, from `iframe`! so i also redefine it ! and your tip works great! @Oscar Paz